# Генерация изображения с waveform из mp3 файлов с помощью PHP

Tags: php, mp3

[image: изображения с waveform]

Есть старенькая статья на эту тему, не смог разобраться что и как.
http://habrahabr.ru/post/112809/

Ссылки в ней многие не работают. Как лучше решить эту задачу? С чего начать? Может уже есть что-то поновее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю два варианта, но оба не встроены в php, а должны быть установлены на сервере заранее.

Свежий [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org) с его фильтром [`showwavespic`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic) отлично умеет рисовать волну:

```
<?php
$workingPath = '/tmp/music.mp3';
$waveformPath = '/tmp/waveform.png';
$cmd = sprintf(
    'ffmpeg  -i "%s"  -y  -r 15  -lavfi showwavespic=s=360x202 "%s"',
    $workingPath,
    $waveformPath
);
@exec( $cmd, $output, $status);
if( $status) {
    // ошибка
}
```

Есть ещё вариант, чуть более сложный, но более интересный. [VAMP plugins](http://vamp-plugins.org/) – это набор утилит для анализа звуковых файлов. Для волновой формы `vamp-example-plugins#amplitudefollower` сделает файл - набор чисел, высот пиков, по которым ужа на клиенте можно рисовать волну: подробную или упрощенную, если пропускать значения, скажем. Другой, `qm-vamp-plugins#qm-barbeattracker`, определяет биты и такты в музыке – файл со временами, на которые приходится сильная доля или граница такта. Вообще, [плагинов – море](http://vamp-plugins.org/download.html), среди них есть очень интересные.

Comment: Честно  говоря я думал, что можно намного проще, такие варианты я сейчас сделать не смогу точно. На сервер устанавливать нет возможности.

Comment: А вот это попробуйте: [php-waveform-png](https://github.com/afreiday/php-waveform-png) – пишут, что требует только PHP5 и LAME mp3 encoder, есть шанс, что он устаноевлен на вашем хостинге.